# Getting coordinates based in direction in Google Maps/Apple Maps in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, maps

Is it possible to get coordinates to be used in Google Maps/Apple Maps (depending on iOS versión) based on a given direction? I've got the directoon (street and number), the post code and the country (in my case, the country will always be Spain)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Geocoder for that, find a guide here:

[Geocoding Location Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW1)

You can find an example at the end of the document:

```
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"1 Infinite Loop"
     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
         {
             // Process the placemark.
         }
}];
```

As they say, the more info you provide, the more accurate will be.